# Pass Service to a Directive

Tags: angularjs

How can I pass a Service to a Directive ?

I want that for each char typed on a text box, I call my service.

**Directive**

```
function campoPesquisa() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<input style='border: none; border-color: transparent; display:none; width: 70%;' type='text' id='txtSearch' placeholder='Search...' />",
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $element.on("keypress", function () {

                });
            }
        }
    }

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('sisloccampopesquisa', campoPesquisa);
```

**In another File**

```
    function comWebApi_Service() {
        // do something here
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .service('apiService', comWebApi_Service);
```

So, I'm using the directive under a controller

```
<div ng-controller="crmContatosCtrl">
   <sisloccampopesquisa></sisloccampopesquisa>
</div>
```

**The Controller crmContatosCtrl**

```
function crmContatosCtrl($scope, apiService) { 
    // some stuff's here
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('crmContatosCtrl', crmContatosCtrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function campoPesquisa(youService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<input style='border: none; border-color: transparent; display:none; width: 70%;' type='text' id='txtSearch' placeholder='Search...' />",
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $element.on("keypress", function () {

                });
            }
        }
    }

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('sisloccampopesquisa', ['apiService', campoPesquisa]);
```